# Most current version of Ubuntu I can run on a Core 2 Duo Macbook pro 7,1?

Tags: macbook

Sorry if this has been asked a million times.  I've tried searching but am not having any luck.  I just installed 10.10 on my MBP 7,1 without issue.  However I would like to run a current and supported version.  I downloaded the latest (13.04) and burned the image.  When I tried to boot from the disc I get a really glitchy page that is unreadable.  After some research it looks like my MBP is not supported on that release.  So I ask, what is the most current version I can run?

Answer (score 0):

[Quantal (12.10)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/) is the latest version with a [support page on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro7-1/Quantal) for that MBP model.

I would also try burning the [Saucy (13.10)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) iso though and following the same instructions to see if the issue you faced with 13.04 is resolved.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to assist.   I think I'll go ahead and trial Quantal this evening and see where that gets me.

Comment: I was able to install 12.10 without issue.  However, after it boots and I login it just freezes.   The curser is unresponsive and I have a row of 18(?) white boxes on the left pane.   From here it does nothing.

Comment: hmm, sounds like a video card issue. Can you get to a command prompt (Ctrl + Alt + F1)? The guide linked above has a section on installing proproetary nVida graphics drivers: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro7-1/Quantal#Video.2BAC8-Graphic_Card else if you can boot in verbose mode and see exactly where things are freezing

Comment: No, I can't get to a command prompt.   When it gets to the login screen it gives a strange little "quick bongo" type sound.  Then it just hangs at that screen I described earlier.   Should I just try the 13.10?   Why is it that the login screen is fine but when I login its not?

Comment: I would try 13.10 but also try the [latest Lubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/current/) to see if it is the Unity desktop causing the graphics incompatibilities on your machine. Though not a great solution to your problem of getting Ubuntu installed on that MBP, I find Lubuntu to perform much better and has all the usual benefits one expects in Ubuntu.

Comment: I was able to get in finally and updated my graphics driver.   It seems to be running.  Sluggish but it is up.  Now onto trying to get xbmc running on it.  My main goal with this machine is to provide a computer that any of our guests can use without having access to my main computers.   Thanks again for your help!

Comment: great! glad you're up and running. If you believe my answer to have solved your original question, please accept the answer here. Also, not to keep throwing more distribution options to you, but there is also [XMBCbuntu](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=XBMCbuntu), which comes optimized with XMBC out of the box. If that can install and is a prominent purpose for the guests, they can still use web browsers and any other Ubuntu software as usual